# Ambiguity in Auto Create\Update Statistics

Tags: sql-server-2012

If I set 'Auto Update Statistics' to 'False' and 'Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously' to 'True'

What the DB will do?

Also - If I set 'Auto Create Statistics' to 'True', It will be 'Async'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ambiguity there.

If you set 'Auto Update Statistics' to 'False' statistics will not be updated automatically.

If you set 'Auto Update Statistics' to 'True' they will be updated according synchronously or asynchronously according to to the 'Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously' settings.

Comment: What about creating statistics? - is it async?

Comment: When the Asyc option is disabled, the Query Optimizer will update the outdated statistics before compiling the query therefore possibly getting a better plan based on the most current statistics.  This is referred to as synchronous statistics updates.http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2904/sql-servers-auto-update-statistics-async-option/

Answer (score 1):

The 'AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS' Option has two possible values, False(off) and True(on).

When set to False, 'AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS' will not update any statistics.

When set to True, 'AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS' will update statistics. The method chosen to update the statistics though depends on the value of the 'AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC' option.

This option has two possible values, False(off) and True(on).

By default, 'AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC' option is False(off) and the statistics update synchronously.

When 'AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC' is True(on) the statistics update asynchronous.